# Query with multiple common table expressions not working?

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, common-table-expression

If I use two common table expressions, one is recursive and one is simple it's not working. If both are simple it's working (it's in HSQL, and Postgres syntax is working)

NOT WORKING

```
WITH RECURSIVE TEMP_TABLE1(NAME) AS 
(
    SELECT child FROM FAMILY where parent='HUMAUN'
    UNION
    SELECT CHILD FROM FAMILY,TEMP_TABLE WHERE PARENT=TEMP_TABLE.NAME
),
TEMP_TABLE2 AS 
(
     SELECT CHILD FROM FAMILY
)
   SELECT CHILD FROM TEMP_TABLE1,TEMP_TABLE2 
   WHERE TEMP_TABLE1.NAME=TEMP_TABLE2.NAME
```

Working if I make temp_table1 to a simple non recursive

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE1(NAME) AS 
(
    SELECT child FROM FAMILY where parent='HUMAUN'
    UNION
    SELECT CHILD FROM FAMILY WHERE PARENT='XYZ'
),
TEMP_TABLE2(NAME) AS 
(
     SELECT CHILD FROM FAMILY
)
   SELECT NAME FROM TEMP_TABLE1,TEMP_TABLE2 
   WHERE TEMP_TABLE1.NAME=TEMP_TABLE2.NAME
```

Comment: If i run those temp_tables individually with a select statement at the end it's working fine .. So both of them returning data and independent to each other ..

Comment: "*not working*" is not a valid HSQLDB error message, nor is it an acceptable problem description.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's saying Unexpected token 'AS' required '(' , mentioning at this line 'TEMP_TABLE2(NAME) AS'  , Error Code -5581

Comment: Which HSQL version are you using?

Comment: Your 'recursive` cte isn't recursive; it selects from `TEMP_TABLE` not `TEMP_TABLE1`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is NOT a solution to the question. I was unaware of the keyword `RECURSIVE`, I'll leave this here for posterity.

---

I think (but I'm not familiar with hsqldb, just sql, though it would fit your error message) your problem is the name of your recursive cte. Could you try:

```
WITH RECURSIVE_TEMP_TABLE1(NAME) AS 
(
    SELECT child FROM FAMILY where parent='HUMAUN'
    UNION
    SELECT CHILD FROM FAMILY,RECURSIVE_TEMP_TABLE1 WHERE PARENT=TEMP_TABLE.NAME
)
```

Note the extra underscore in the cte name. Also, to make it really recursive, the bottom part of the `union` should select from itself, so `RECURSIVE_TEMP_TABLE1`.

Comment: HSQLDB syntax is SQL Standard and requites the RECURSIVE keyword after WITH. Some other database servers do not require it.

Comment: @fredt, fair enough, this won't solve OP's question then. I thought it might be the case, but I couldn't find a reference for recursive CTE's in hsqldb.